# export to MP3 from quicktime API

Tags: macos, quicktime

A question for Apple,QT programmers.

Would like to know if it's possible to export a Movie object to MP3 using the QuickTime API. Preferably the ConvertMovieToFile function. I've looked at QTComponentTypes.h but don't see an entry for MP3.

I need to export audio in a format that can do > 4GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done due to codec licensing issues.

Though these issues may go away since they've stopped charging money for QuickTime.